# What's the best WCF security mode when SSL is not an option

Tags: c#, wcf, security

I have a WCF which has very few light methods. This service is used over internet.

Unfortunately I cannot use `SSL` but still needed to authenticate clients with a `Username/Password`. Also due to firewall restrictions I prefer port 80 for communication.

Which WCF security mode should I use for my scenario ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement [message level security over HTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731058.aspx).